# AngularJS: groups of checkboxes inside a loop

Tags: angularjs

There are some categories inside `ng-repeat`, and each one includes some accounts, If each category is selected then all accounts inside it must be selected and vice versa. Also, if one account is not selected, then the parent category is not selected.

How can I do that?

Here is how the view is:

[image]

And the code fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2f6qscrp/208/

Thank you for any help.

Comment: cant see any check box in snippet output

Comment: I dont know why.. !! they dont appear only in the snippet, on my computer they appear well @AnilKumarRam

Comment: I've added a  fiddle :) @AnilKumarRam

Comment: @HalaElBarchah check the fiddle in my answer below

Comment: It works, Thank you :) @Aruna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working fiddle for your case,

http://jsfiddle.net/balasuar/2f6qscrp/209/

HTML

```
<div ng-app='home'>
    <!-- App goes here -->
    <md-content layout-padding ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">   
            <md-checkbox ng-model="selectedAll"
                         ng-change="toggleAll()"
                         class="md-primary">
              <span ng-if="selectedAll">Un-</span>Select All
            </md-checkbox>         
            <div ng-repeat="category in naturalAccounts">
              <md-checkbox class="md-primary"  ng-model="category.selected" ng-change="toggleCategory(category)">
               {{ category.name }}
              </md-checkbox>
              <div ng-repeat="acc in category.accounts">                           
                 <md-checkbox class="md-primary" ng-model="acc.selected" ng-change="toggleAccount(category, acc)" >{{acc.name}}</md-checkbox>
               </div>
               </div>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('home', ['ngAria', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial']);

angular.module('home').config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
        .primaryPalette('pink')
        .accentPalette('grey');
});

angular.module('home').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.naturalAccounts = [
            {"id":0,"name":"category0","accounts":[{"id":0,"name":"acc0"},{"id":1,"name":"acc1"},{"id":2,"name":"acc2"}] },
            {"id":1,"name":"category1","accounts":[{"id":0,"name":"acc0"},{"id":1,"name":"acc1"},{"id":2,"name":"acc2"}] },
            {"id":2,"name":"category2","accounts":[{"id":0,"name":"acc0"},{"id":1,"name":"acc1"},{"id":2,"name":"acc2"}] }
        ];

        $scope.selectedAll = false;

        function setSelectedAll() {
           for(var i = 0; i < $scope.naturalAccounts.length; i++) {
              var category = $scope.naturalAccounts[i];
              $scope.selectedAll = category.selected;
              if(!$scope.selectedAll) {
                 break;
              }
           }
        }

        $scope.toggleAll = function() {
             for(var i = 0; i < $scope.naturalAccounts.length; i++) {
              var category = $scope.naturalAccounts[i];
              category.selected = $scope.selectedAll;

              for(var j = 0; j < category.accounts.length; j++) {
                 var account = category.accounts[j];
                 account.selected = $scope.selectedAll;             
              }
           }
        };

        $scope.toggleCategory = function(category) {
             for(var j = 0; j < category.accounts.length; j++) {
                 var account = category.accounts[j];
                 account.selected = category.selected;             
           }

           setSelectedAll();
        };

        $scope.toggleAccount = function(category, account) {
             for(var j = 0; j < category.accounts.length; j++) {
                 var account = category.accounts[j];
                 category.selected = account.selected;  
                 if(!category.selected) {
                    break;
                 }           
           }

           setSelectedAll();
        };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="category.checked" ng-change="checkAllAccountsOfCategoryIfChecked(category)" />
```

and

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="account.checked" ng-change="checkOrUncheckCategoryBasedOnItsAccounts(category)" />
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.checkAllAccountsOfCategoryIfChecked = function(category) {
    // TODO if category is checked, then loop over all its accounts and check them
}

$scope.checkOrUncheckParentCategory = function(category) {
    // TODO if all the category's accounts are checked, 
    // then check the category, otherwise uncheck it
}
```